# How to create a database backup in DBeaver and restore it?

Tags: sql-server, dbeaver

I need to create a SQL server database backup in DBeaver and restore it. Is that possible?

Using SQL Management Studio would not be a turnaround solution in this case, as we are not allowed to use it here.

Comment: Seems very odd to not be able to use SSMS, which is the tool designed by Microsoft to access their own Database Engine. But yes, it's possible, the SQL you run doesn't change depending on the interface you're using. the `BACKUP` statement would be identical to one one you would run in SSMS, `sqlcmd`,VS Code, SQL Azure Studio, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: [BACKUP (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#sql-server)

Comment: You aren't allowed to use SSMS? I'd be putting out a resume.

Answer (score 7):

According to DBeaver documentation:

> DBeaver supports native database backup/restore functions for
> following databases:
>
> ```
> PostgreSQL
> MySQL
> ```

So it looks like currently DBeaver (as of version 7.3) does not support this featire for SQL Server.

[DBeaver Backup/Resore documentation](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Backup-Restore/)